# Substring a result and renaming it

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, substring

I wrote the below query which works just fine. 
The `PARAM_ID` has a `CLC_Q<number>` form.

```
SELECT * FROM DB.TABLE 
    WHERE PARAM_ID LIKE 'CLC_Q%' 
    AND SUBSTR(PARAM_ID,6) BETWEEN 35 AND 45 
    ORDER BY SUBSTR(PARAM_ID,6) ASC;
```

It might be a logical mistake , but I can't do the below,

```
SELECT SUBSTR(PARAM_ID,6) PAR_ID FROM DB.TABLE 
    WHERE PARAM_ID LIKE 'CLC_Q%' 
    AND PAR_ID BETWEEN 35 AND 45 
    ORDER BY PAR_ID ASC;
```

Although it's a different question, I can't also do this,

```
SELECT SUBSTR(PARAM_ID,6),* FROM DB.TABLE -- The change is in this line
    WHERE PARAM_ID LIKE 'CLC_Q%' 
    AND SUBSTR(PARAM_ID,6) BETWEEN 35 AND 45 
    ORDER BY SUBSTR(PARAM_ID,6) ASC;
```

**Version**

```
Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
```

Any further suggestions on how to improve my query would be much appreciated.

Comment: About the 3rd query. Can you do `SELECT *, SUBSTR(PARAM_ID,6) PAR_ID` instead?

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Comment: @ypercube Nope, still getting an error.

Comment: Oh yes, it's Oracle. You need `SELECT tablename.*, SUBSTR(PARAM_ID,6) PAR_ID` or `SELECT SUBSTR(PARAM_ID,6) PAR_ID,  tablename.*`

Comment: And do you really have a table named `table`?

Answer (score 1):

Using a CTE will do what you want:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT SUBSTR(PARAM_ID,6) AS PAR_ID, T.* FROM DB.TABLE T
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE PARAM_ID LIKE 'CLC_Q%' 
AND PAR_ID BETWEEN 35 AND 45 
ORDER BY PAR_ID ASC;
```

or simply using `table_alias.*`, instead of `*`:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(PARAM_ID,6) AS PAR_ID, T.* FROM DB.TABLE T
    WHERE PARAM_ID LIKE 'CLC_Q%' 
    AND SUBSTR(PARAM_ID,6) BETWEEN 35 AND 45 
    ORDER BY PAR_ID ASC;
```